# How Can I add Octave in PATH environment variable in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, path, octave

I would like to add Octave in my PATH environment variable. Is there a lineguide like the following?

http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Impossible to tell, what you're looking for. The title talks about *"Ocatave"*, while the text asks about *"Octave"*. I don't know what a *"lineguide"* is either, or which part of the java.com-link is not sufficient for your purposes. There's also no hint about what tools you would like to use, what programming language a solution should be in, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you installed Octave in a folder `myOctave`, and the path to it is `myPath` which may be something like `C:\Program Files\`. Then, you could launch the `cmd` of your windows, and type the following

```
set PATH=%PATH%;myPath\myOctave\bin
```

Here is a detailed example based on my own Octave path and directory. My Octave is installed here `E:\Programs\Octave\Octave-4.0.0`, and thus under the `cmd` window, I run

```
set PATH=%PATH%;E:\Programs\Octave\Octave-4.0.0\bin
```

Then you are all set.

if you run open Command promt and type octave --gui ( it will open Graphical interface)
else if you just type octave (it will open command interface).

Answer (score 2):

Just type `addpath('requiredPath')` in the Octave command prompt.

Comment: The OP Is not asking how to add folders to Octave search path.

Comment: not working `warning: addpath: requiredPath: No such file or directory`